# My tensorflow model has high accuracy but can't predict even the train data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

It is my first NN model that I wrote from scratch and I have trained it for 60 epochs, it has 95% accuracy and approximately the same amount of accuracy on the validation set. Despite of it when I predict it misses every single time even on images in the training set itself.

It is an image classification network for recognizing playing cards, the model itself is the same:

```
image_size = 256
channels = 3

def create_model(in_shape=(image_size, image_size, channels)):
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4,4), padding='same', input_shape=in_shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.3))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(.3))
    model.add(Dense(53, activation='softmax'))
    
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=.001)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()
    return model
```

I train it with dataset created by **keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory**

The metrics for epoch#46 that I used for prediction are the next:

```
accuracy 0.9460561871528625, loss 0.16653507947921753
val_accuracy 0.9509981870651245, val_loss 0.17450878024101257
```

What could be the issue?

prediction code is the next:

```
model = create_model()
train, val, classes = createDataset('labeled/resized')

model.load_weights('latestWeights5')

images = []
for image in os.listdir('for test'):
    images.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join('for test', image)))

arr = np.array(images)
arr = np.divide(arr, 255)
result = model.predict(arr)

for pred in result:
    print(classes[np.where(pred == np.max(pred))[0][0]])
```

where createDataset is the next:

```
def createDataset(directory):
    train_ds = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'labeled/resized',
        validation_split= .2,
        subset='training',
        seed=42,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    val_ds = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'labeled/resized',
        validation_split= .2,
        subset='validation',
        seed=42,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    
    classes = train_ds.class_names

    train_ds = train_ds.map(process)
    val_ds = val_ds.map(process)

    return train_ds, val_ds, classes
```

and process is:

```
def process(image,label):
    image = tf.cast(image/255. ,tf.float32)
    return image,label
```

Comment: You need to include the prediction code, which seems to be the point of failure.